# Spring Tool Suite & ADT: The following connectors are not available: Android Development Tools

Tags: java, android, spring

I am using a MAC with OS X Mavericks and I am trying to install the ADT plugin on my Spring Tool Suite installation (version 3.5.1.RELEASE).

I am trying to follow this tutorial -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=im1gJuYUiUk

It seems very easy to do, however when I click on IDE Extensions, select the Android Development Tools and click Install, I get the following error:

**The following connectors are not available: Android Development Tools Proceed with the installation anyways?**

Anyway, if I click "Yes" or "No" I get this error:

```
Problems occurred while performing installation: The following connectors are not    
available: Android Development Tools (id=com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group, 
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group, 
com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group, 
com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group, site=https://dl-  
ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)
The following connectors are not available: Android Development Tools  
(id=com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group, com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group,  
com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group,  
com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group, site=https://dl- 
ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)
```

I scoured the net but didn't find anything about the problem.

What should I do? Why it isn't working in my case and in the video I posted does?

Thanks you for the attention!